# Manage the multiple row in Overleaf

Tags: latex, row, tabular

I have made a table with multiple columns and rows arguments like this

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Aspects} & Probability & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Methods} \\
\cline{3-6}
& for DE Genes          & Binomial Test & Tangram & stereoscope & BayesPrism\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{AUC}  & 0.3   & 0.867 & 0.029 & 0.074 & 0.992 \\
                  & 0.1   & 0.722 & 0.023 & 0.015 & 0.987\\
                  & 0.05  & 0.512 & 0.055 & 0.025 & 0.972\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Best Thresholds} & 0.3   & ${0.135$ & 0.029 & 0.072 & $1e-10$ \\
                             & 0.1   & ${1e-60$ & 0.026 & 0.065 & $1e-10$\\
                             & 0.05  & $1e-60$ & 0.033 & 0.069 & $1e-10$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The ROC Curve Summary for Data with 15 Clusters}
\label{15 cluster summary}
\end{table}
```

It will give the results like this [image]

I want to make the entries "Best Thresholds" be in two rows (filling 3 rows arguments) so that the table is not too wide. Could anyone helps how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can place the text in a `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Aspects} & Probability & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Methods} \\
\cline{3-6}
& for DE Genes          & Binomial Test & Tangram & stereoscope & BayesPrism\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{AUC}  & 0.3   & 0.867 & 0.029 & 0.074 & 0.992 \\
                  & 0.1   & 0.722 & 0.023 & 0.015 & 0.987\\
                  & 0.05  & 0.512 & 0.055 & 0.025 & 0.972\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{\raggedright Best Thresholds}} & 0.3   & $0.135$ & 0.029 & 0.072 & $1e-10$ \\
                             & 0.1   & $1e-60$ & 0.026 & 0.065 & $1e-10$\\
                             & 0.05  & $1e-60$ & 0.033 & 0.069 & $1e-10$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The ROC Curve Summary for Data with 15 Clusters}
\label{15 cluster summary}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```